# Counting occurrences of strings in an Array

Tags: arrays, string, asp-classic, web

I am basically pasting this from another forum where I saw it asked (with nobody answering).  It is essentially the exact same thing im trying to do:

In ASP classic, is there a way to count the number of times a string appears in an array of strings and output them based on string and occurrence count?

For example if I have an array which contains the following :
hello
happy
hello
hello
testing
hello
test
happy

The output would be:

hello 4
happy 2
test 1
testing 1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the language is VBScript (since that's what most people use with classic ASP).

You can use a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28VS.84%29.aspx) object to keep track of the individual counts:

```
Function CountValues(pArray)
    Dim i, item
    Dim dictCounts
    Set dictCounts = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(pArray) To UBound(pArray)
        item = pArray(i)
        If Not dictCounts.Exists(item) Then
            dictCounts.Add item, 0
        End If
        dictCounts.Item(item) = dictCounts.Item(item) + 1
    Next

    Set CountValues = dictCounts
End Function
```